# Fastify with NextJS and next-i18next - res.header is not a function

Tags: node.js, next.js, i18next, fastify

I am trying to implement `NextJS, Fastify and next-i18next`, but I am getting this error, when I try to access a route in the browser:

> TypeError: res.header is not a function
>
> app folder\node_modules\next-i18next\dist\commonjs\utils\redirect-without-cache.js:11
>     res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');

This is a `server.js` file, from where I am starting both Fastify and NextJS:

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: { level: 'error' } })
const Next = require('next')
const nextI18NextMiddleware = require('next-i18next/middleware').default;

const nextI18next = require('./config/next-i18next');

fastify.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));

fastify.register((fastify, opts, next) => {

    const app = Next({ dev })


    const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

    app.prepare().then(() => {

           fastify.get('/api/places', (req, reply) => {
             return reply.send({hello: 90})
           })

           fastify.all('/*', (req, reply) => {
             return handle(req.req, reply.res).then(() => {
                 reply.sent = true
             })
          })
          next();

   }).catch(err => next(err));

})
```

... listen

I guess why is this error. This line - `fastify.use(nextI18NextMiddleware(nextI18next));`, but it doesn't metter, where I place it, always is the same error. I have read that in the new version of `Fastify` the express middleware will be a plugin, but I am using `"fastify": "^2.14.1"`.

Comment: You are having an error because some plugin isn't compatible with Fastify. It is easy to mismatch methods called on `request` and `response` (`reply` in fastify) when using plugins that are designed say for `Express` or `HTTP` ... and then used for `Fastify` for instance (and vice versa)